# Adding to a TreeView a ResourceDictionary from another Assembly

Tags: wpf, treeview, resourcedictionary, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a TreeView element which I'm trying to sets its DataTemplates from a resource dictionary which is defined in another Assembly. I'm using quite a simplate approach:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Vehicles}">
            <TreeView.Resources>                
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/CarsLib;component/TreeTemplateDictionary.xaml"/>
                    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
```

However. This does not seems to work. I debugged it and noticed that the ResourceDictionary was loaded. Please help me understand what am I missing. The ResourceDictionary looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CarsLib">
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="StationTreeViewTemplate"
                          DataType="{x:Type local:Station}" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FamounsModels}">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="3,3,3,3" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=EngineSize}" Margin="3,3,3,3" />
    </DockPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Thanks,

Izhar Lotem

Comment: please provide some datatamplate xaml from TreeTemplateDictionary.xaml, do you want to set TreeView datatemplate with key or type?

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve this bug. I removed to  `x:Key` from the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` inside the `ResourceDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually trying to do something like that until I found a solution.
From your code I believe that the assembly that contains the resources you are trying to load\set is called "CarsLib.dll" or at least the Assembly is internally called "CarsLib".
That said, I believe that your code should become like:

**YourXamlWithTheTreeView.xaml**

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Vehicles}">
    <TreeView.Resources>                
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Carslib;component/TreeTemplateDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```